# Can't install PIL on MAC OS X 10.12

Tags: python-3.x, macos-sierra, python-imaging-library

I've just updated my OS and cannot import PIL. I installed Xcode after I updated my OS so that is up to date. I've seen many answers on this site refer to older versions of MAC OS X but nothing has worked for me. I installed Pillow as that was the advice given in another answer.
I installed Pillow with
    `brew install pillow`

In my module I have
    `from PIL import Image`

And I'm getting the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

Comment: Can you edit your question to show *how* you installed Pillow? Do you perhaps have both Python2 and Python3 installed?

Comment: I have just checked and yes I have Python2 and Python3 installed. Should I remove one of these versions?

Comment: Well, Python 2 comes with macos and is used by some system programs so you can't remove that. But Python 3 is the future, so I would keep that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both Python 2 and Python 3 installed.
Python 2 comes with macos. So the program `python` is probably a link to `python2.7`.

You didn't mentioned *how* you installed Python 3. If you haven't done so, it is probably *easiest in the long run* is to use a package manager like [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

This is because an imaging library like Pillow needs certain shared libraries to work properly. Homebrew's recipes will make sure that these are installed when you install pillow.
The same goes for other useful packages like `numpy`.

So, delete your Python 3 version. Install homebrew and use it to install Python 3 and pillow.

Comment: This worked for me. I followed your instructions exactly, reinstalled IDLE and no longer got the error message I mentioned above. I also had to change my import statement from "from PIL import Image" to "import PIL.Image" and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To Add onto @Roland_Smith's answer

This worked for me

`brew install homebrew/science/pillow`